# unhandled Promise rejection: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular4-router

i work on a angular 4 project as  front end for an asp.net MVC and API in the same solution  when  i set  my  routes  i get  the above   error.
my code as following

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule   } from '@angular/common';


 import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from 
'../../Components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
 import { TraitComponent } from '../../Components/trait/trait.component';

  const routes: Routes = [
     { path: ' ', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent  },
     { path: 'Trait', component: TraitComponent },
      //{ path: 'heroes', component:  }
    ];
     @NgModule({
      imports: [
       RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ,
                                      CommonModule
                                                         ],

exports: [RouterModule],
```

})
export class MyAppRoutingModuleModule {

i register/import the "myapprouting "and in my appmodule
that is code in my appComponent

```
<nav>
            <a routerLink="localhost:56800/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            <a routerLink="localhost:56800/Trait">Heroes</a>
        </nav>
        <!--  <app-trait></app-trait>-->
        <router-outlet>


        </router-outlet>
```

Comment: Have u added `<base href=”/”>` in your index.html

Comment: yes  i  tried  that   and still have error of :-
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'localhost:56800/dashboard'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'localhost:56800/dashboard'

Answer (score 6):

In your **app.module.ts**, add the following :

```
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
```

to your **providers : [ ] ** so it would be like this :

```
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},SomeService,AnotherService]
```

Comment: if  i set   ' providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],  i  got error  say :- errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'localhost:56800/dashboard'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'localhost:56800/dashboard'
and  if i set       providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'http://localhost:56800/' }],
i got the  same error

Answer (score 1):

> app.module.ts

```
        import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'; <-- add those ***

        const appRoutes: Routes = [
          { path: 'secondpage', component: SecondPageComponent },

        ];
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            NameEditorComponent,
            ProfileEditorComponent,
            SecondPageComponent
          ],
          imports: [

            BrowserModule,
            // other imports ...
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(
              appRoutes,
              { enableTracing: true } //
            )
          ],
          providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}], <-- add those ****        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the routerLink to this :

```
[routerLink]="['/dashboard']
[routerLink]="['/Trait']
```

Comment: the  problem is solved  there was an extra /   in my  code  thanks  and regard

Comment: GLad you fixed it